# how to refresh a XML external?

Tags: java, android, xml, refresh, external

I read an external xml and I call the refresh function. How? my code:

```
try {

        URL url = new URL("http://humildadysoledad.es/APP/actuaciones.xml");
        DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
        Document doc = db.parse(new InputSource(url.openStream()));
        doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();
        NodeList nodeList = doc.getElementsByTagName("item");

 // ...
```

Comment: which language is this in? Java?

Comment: yes, the code is in Java (Android)

Comment: I have retagged your question. Using the proper tags helps to get your question at the proper people. Be prepaired to add more details to your question because to me it is not clear where and how you want to call the refresh function, nor what it is. But I'm far from a java/android type of guy so maybe I'm wrong.

Comment: sorry i am nookie! thanks!